# Values not staying set in java

Tags: java

I have two classes, a snake class, and a block class. I am coding a snake game. The block is each piece of the snake. A snake is the whole creature, which is really just an array of blocks(which I called body). The constructor of block allows me to set the x, the y, and the position in the array of it. However, when I set these values for the 3 blocks in the body, it just says all the blocks in the array have the values of the 3rd block. (the System.out.print results in 100,100,100 instead of 140,120,100)

```
body[0] = new block( 140, 320, 0);
    body[1] = new block(120,320,1);
    body[2] = new block(100,320,2);
    System.out.println(body[0].rect.x+","+body[1].rect.x+","+body[2].rect.x);
```

Here is my block class.

```
public class block {
public static Rectangle rect; 
private static int size = 20;
public static int position; 
public block(int x, int y, int locator){
    rect = new Rectangle(x,y,size,size);
    position = locator;
}
}
```

Comment: The problem likely lies in your `block` class. Please show us your implementation of it.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Please post the classes you are referring to.

Comment: I posted my block class. The snake class currently only has a constructor, in which the code where the error occurs is all it contains.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but your block class isn't great coding. You should make the `rect` and `position` variables private and create a getter and setter methods for them

Comment: i will need them public for later in the code

Comment: oh never mind getter and setter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using static attributes in your `block` class. Static attributes are the same across all instances of a class. You should be using non-static attributes.

```
public class block {
    public Rectangle rect; 
    private static int size = 20;
    public int position; 
    public block(int x, int y, int locator){
        rect = new Rectangle(x,y,size,size);
        position = locator;
    }
}
```

The `size` attribute is fine as static since you want all the blocks to be the same size anyway.

Some additional advice:

- your `block` class should be named as `Block` as per Java convention.
- the attributes in your `block` class should be set to private and be accessed through getter and setter methods.

Comment: Thanks this worked. Would you mind explaining what static really means and/or does.

Comment: You can think of it as a common attribute of the class. If you change a static attribute in one instance, all the other instances will also receive the change. You can read more about it here: https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because of how you've set up your block class. Because you've made the `rect` and `position` variables public, they are not instances of the object. When you use your constructor, it is setting the value of the public variable `rect`, instead of creating an instance variable `rect` of the block class.